# how to retrieve the ID of the Link in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am having a situation here ... please consider the following scenario

1) value coming from the database eg: personName ( whos id in the database is 3 )

2) i am making a link of the " personName " through @Html.ActionLink

3) the link id is "lnkName"

i want to retrieve the id of the personName which is 3 when the lnkName is clicked. please help me ..

here is my code for the link..

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <h3>  @Html.ActionLink(item.personName, "Details", "Post", new { Id = item.personID } , new { @id = "lnkName" } ) </h3>
```

here is the Jquery code i have got so far...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lnkName').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                    url: @Url.Action("AddViews","Post")
                    data: // how can i retrieve the id of the clicked link which is 3
                });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the link is clicked, you can get it's `id` via the `this` variable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lnkName').click(function () {
            var id = this.id;     // <=== you can fetch the id of the clicked link via "this"
            $.ajax({
                    url: @Url.Action("AddViews","Post"),
                    data: id
                });
            return(false);
        });
});
```

If it's not the CSS ID that you want here (I wasn't sure in your question), but some other piece of data like the personID, then you should put that other piece of data as a data attribute on the link tag and fetch that attribute with jQuery using `$(this).data("xxx")`.

For example, if the link generated by your server-side code looked like this:

```
<a href="xxx" class="lnkName" data-personID="3">
```

Then, in your click handler, you can fetch that personID like this (and then you would have to put it into your ajax parameters however you want it to be sent):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lnkName').click(function () {
            var personID = parseInt($(this).attr("data-personID"), 10);  // <===
            $.ajax({
                    url: @Url.Action("AddViews","Post"),
                    data: personID
                });
            return(false);
        });
});
```

Comment: This won't work. It won't send an AJAX request when the link is clicked.

Comment: What do you mean?  If you fill in the appropriate data in your ajax call (which I left for you to do) and you define a success handler to handle the ajax response, it absolutely will make an ajax call when the link is clicked.  Why do you think it won't work?

Comment: If the jQuery click handler isn't working, then that's a problem with your HTML.  Show us the client-side generated HTML (from View/Page Source in the browser) and we can help better with that.  Many who could help here don't know how to read your server-side pages that will get turned into something else before reaching the browser.

Comment: look at the comment towards the end of the anonymous `click` callback I have left in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541696/how-to-retirve-the-id-of-the-link-in-jquery-asp-net-mvc-3/7541733#7541733) to understand why it won't work.

Comment: Look at my second example in my answer.  It uses a data-personID attribute to put the appropriate personID into the link and then fetches that out at click-time.

Comment: yes I see it. Still it won't work. Did you read my answer to understand why it won't work?

Comment: Feedback incorporated.  "Won't work" isn't very specific - it would be nice if you include a little more info next time.

Comment: well, I have included all the necessary info in my answer. Still this `@Url.Action("AddViews","Post")` in your javascript bothers me. It means that you are putting this javascript inside the view meaning that you are mixing markup and script which is not considered good practice in a web site. It leads to increased HTML size with impossibility to cache it and serve from a CDN, which is really crucial if you care about performance and want to optimize the site.

Comment: I just left that the way the OP had it.  I was solving the problem of getting the personID into the data arguments for the ajax call.  I thought that was the question that was being asked.  I didn't try to improve everything else that could use improvement.  I'm done arguing with you.  I'd he happy to answer any questions the OP might have.

Comment: yes I see that. Personally when I answer a question I always try to give the best answer from my point of view and provide with hints of improving the OPs code. StackOverflow is a pretty well referenced site and there might be people in the future coming across this post with the same problem and we want them to get the best solution for each case. Not just answer a question and get some reputation, it's really not the point of StackOverflow.

Comment: @jfriend00: your answer looks good to me ... i can add as many data i want in link using the data- attribute and retrieve the data in Ajax..
Darin Dimitrov: you are right ... the ajax call is failing ...

what i wanted is to call 2 different action on the same controller to perform 2 different database tasks. so until and unless in jquery i am not preventing the default link behavior, its not calling the ajax. so is there any way to call the ajax and not preventing the default behavior ?

Comment: @patel.milanb, what do you mean by invoking 2 different actions on the server from the same link? This doesn't make sense. Or are you talking about trigerring 2 AJAX requests when the link is clicked?

Comment: That's fine Darin.  I don't know anything about the server-side stuff being used here - just trying to help from the client-side perspective so that's how I try to help.  This could also be perceived as a general purpose question (independent of server back-end) about how to put data into a link which can be retrieved upon click and I've offered an option using a data-xxx attribute.

Comment: basically i wanted 2 database action to be taken on clicking the link. one is adding the count and one is showing the details. if i put all code in one Controller action its working fine BUT my controller action code is getting heavy and so i thought if its possible to call 2 action on the server when link clicked so that i can differentiate the database tasks in a separate controller action 1 is for details and 1 is for adding ..

Comment: @patel.milanb.  If you really want to, you can just launch two seperate ajax calls from the click.  If you `return(false)` from the click handler, then the default action of the link won't cancel your ajax calls.

Comment: returning false from a click handler in jQuery will automatically call `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`, so all you need to do is make sure you `return(false)` from the event handler which will allow your ajax calls to process.

Answer (score 2):

Generate the link the way it should be, directly containing the correct url in the href property. This way you don't need to worry about it:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    item.personName, 
    "AddViews", // <!-- modify the action so that it directly points to the correct one
    "Post", 
    new { id = item.personID }, 
    new { @class = "lnkName" } // <!-- Notice that I use a class here instead of an id because ids must be unique in the DOM and in your code you have multiple links with the same id resulting into invalid markup
)
```

and then in a separate javascript file you could unobtrusively AJAXify this anchor:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lnkName').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });

        // that's important in order to cancel the default action
        // or the browser will simply redirect to the url and the AJAX
        // call will never have time to execute
        return false;
    });
});
```

This way you could put your javascript in a completely separate js file, the way it should be. And benefit of course from minifying it, gzipping it, caching it and even serving it from a CDN. Always try to put javascript in separate files and avoid them depending on server side expressions such as `@Url.Action`. I have shown you a way to avoid such undesired dependency.

Comment: Can you explain how the personID gets passed to the ajax call?

Comment: @jfriend00, it's part of the url generated by the Html.ActionLink helper. It's the `new { id = item.personID }` bit in fact that does this and based on the routing configuration generates the proper `href` tag for the anchor containing the correct person id.